# Outputting data from the database to the android table with a fixed column

Tags: android, listview, horizontal-scrolling

How to output data from a DB in the android table so that the first column at horizontal was fixed (the table rather wide)?
I created 2 ListView: one (`lvBrigade`) for the first column, the second (`lvMain`) for the rest of the table (it has a horizontal scroll bar). Each `lvBrigade` item is 1 `TextView`. Each `lvMain` item is a few `TextView's`. To synchronize the scrolling, I call the listener using the `setOnScrollChangeListener` method and then obtaining the `scrollY` coordinate (in this case, the `scrollY`) of one `ListView`, I set the scroll coordinate to the second `ListView`. Of course, it does not work for me. Maybe it can be implemented somehow with the help of other View-elements?
Here the code:

```
lvMain.setOnScrollChangeListener(new View.OnScrollChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onScrollChange(View v, int scrollX, int scrollY, int oldScrollX, int oldScrollY) {
            lvBrigade.scrollTo(0, scrollY);
        }
    });
```

I also tried the listeners `OnScrollListener` and `OnTouchListener` and also 0 reactions - `ListViews` do not cling to each other.

Comment: Create custom layout row for your table and inflate by the time when data row added from db

Comment: btw do u have any output